# UITableView not refreshing after calling tableView.reloadData on main thread

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Update: My call to `let vc = viewControllers(for: self)` was returning the wrong values, so the update wasn't triggering.

I'm trying to update a `UITableView` with the `tableView.reloadData` method, but it's not triggering an update?

The update should happen when `selectAndHighlight` is called from the parent view controller when a search result is clicked

Ive searched around, and from what I can tell, I needed to call the update on the main thread, so I've done that, but I'm still not getting any updates?

In the long term, I'll probably only want to update a single cell, but for now, I just want anything to update, which doesn't work.  There is no log output from my print statement during the reload command.

When I scroll the content off the screen then back on, the new content is there correctly, so the data is sync'ing properly, it's just not updating.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import XLPagerTabStrip

class ArtistViewControllerTableViewController: UITableViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider {

open var stageName = ""

var artists: Results<Artist>!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    artists = try! realm.objects(Artist.self).filter("stageName = '" + stageName + "'")

    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArtistCell", for: indexPath)
    as! ArtistCellTableViewCell

    let artist = artists[indexPath.row] as Artist

    cell.artist = artist

    print ("updating " + artist.artistName)

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Artist Clicked")
}

open func selectAndHighlight(artist: Artist) {

    print (stageName)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let realm = try! Realm()

        try! realm.write {
            artist.artistName = "new name"
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    } 
}  

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return artists.count
}

func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    return IndicatorInfo(title: stageName)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

The extension that ends up calling the SelectAndHighlight method after a search result is clicked.

```
extension ParentViewController: HandleSearchResultClick{
func select(artist: Artist) {
    print(artist.artistName + " clicked")
    var x = 0

    let vc = viewControllers(for: self)
    let table = vc[x] as? ArtistViewControllerTableViewController
    table?.selectAndHighlight(artist: artist)     
}
}
```

Comment: where did you call selectAndHighlight?

Comment: In the parent view controller that manages all the tabs.  It's through a protocol, and that protocol is working.  The print(stageName) triggers and it's the correct print.  I updated the post to mention the protocol

Comment: Sorry, that one isn't a protocol, It's just me getting a reference to the view controller, when a search result is clicked.

let table = vc[x] as? ArtistViewControllerTableViewController
table?.selectAndHighlight(artist: artist)

Comment: Your ParentViewController does not know anything about the tableView so it can not reload its data, you should pass it to ParentViewController somehow, for example with segue

Comment: The ParentViewController is subclass of ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController which basically knows about all it's child view controllers.  I'm basically accessing the child at a certain position, which is the UITableViewController.  the SelectAndHighlight method in the proper view controller is being called, so that seems correct to me?  Why can it call the method and not update the table?

Comment: Because it is an instance of the VC and the views of child are all nil. try putting a textField in the childView and update the text property this way, you see it won't get set. you have to pass the view to it too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134271/discussion-between-ben987654-and-mohsen-hossein-pour).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling following func before calling `tableView.reloadData()`

```
func refreshArtistsObj(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    artists = try! realm.objects(Artist.self).filter("stageName = '" + stageName + "'")
}
```

The problem is after adding value to RealmDB you need to fetch updated value and update your artists object again.

Comment: That's not working.  The data is refreshing properly without me calling an update to the realm list, it's the tableview that isn't calling the "tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell" after I call reloadData